# Big Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Just need a confirmation on something real quick. 
If an algorithm takes `n(n-1)/2` tests to run, is the big oh `O(n^2)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

n(n-1)/2 expands to `(n^2 -n) / 2`, that is `(n^2/2) - (n/2)`

`(n^2/2)` and `(n/2)` are the two functions components, of which `n^2/2` dominates. 
Therefore, we can ignore the `- (n/2)` part.

From `n^2/2` you can safely remove the /2 part in asymptotic notation analysis.

This simplifies to
`n^2`

Therefore yes, it is in O(n^2)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is correct.

`n(n-1)/2` expands to `n^2/2 - n/2`:

The linear term `n/2` drops off because it's of lower order. This leaves `n^2/2`. The constant gets absorbed into the big-O, leaving `n^2`.

Comment: @Jay, you should accept the answer if you believe that is satisfies your question

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
n(n-1)/2 = (n2-n)/2 = O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. `n(n-1)/2` is `(n^2 - n)/2`, which is clearly smaller than `c*n^2` for all `n>=1` if you pick a `c` that's at least 1.