# Algorithm Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am studying an algorithm that in the worst case performs a number of operations like this:

```
N + (N -1) + (N - 2) + (N - 3) + ... + [N - (N -1)] + (N -N)
```

In the Big O notation analysis is this algorithm Linear, quadratic or something else?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you think? Give us some analysis.

Comment: It isn't a homework.. and sorry if the question is stupid. I found a good answer here : stackoverflow.com/questions/8261895/big-oh-notation

Comment: that's a link to this post :)

Comment: Sorry :) I meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261895/big-oh-notation

Comment: For future reference, [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28N-i%29+from+i%3D0+to+i+%3D+N) is your friend in these kinds of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is the "small Gauss". It equals to n(n+1)/2.

[image: Gauss' Trick equation]

This is O( (n*n + n)/2 ) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 6):

This is math. Your sum is exactly equal to `N*(N+1)/2`

Comment: Thanks. After your answer i found this useful link stackoverflow.com/questions/8261895/big-oh-notation