# Given an array, count the pairs whose sums are multiples of 60

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Given an array, how do you find the number of couples (two values) that add up to 60 or a value divisible by 60. Note: Must be faster than O(N^2).

Input: [10, 50, 30, 90]
Output: 2 
Reasoning: 10+50 = 60, 30 + 90 = 120 ( 120 is divisible by 60)

Input: [60,60,60]
Output: 3
Reasoning: 60 + 60 = 120, 60 + 60 = 120, 60 + 60 = 120

The code I have below would run in O(N) time, but I do not know how to take care of the pairs that are equal to each other (ie if you have 2 30 values in the array that would add 1 to your counter, but if you have 3 30 values in the array that would add 3 to your counter). I figured I should create a combination function (ie 2C2 or 3C2), but that is a linear function and wouldn't that just make the function back to O(N^2)?

```
values(myList) {
    var obj = {};
    var count = 0;

    // loop through array and mod each value and insert it into a dictionary
    myList.forEach((elem, index) => {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(elem % 60)) {
            obj[elem % 60] = 1;
        } else {
            obj[elem % 60]++;
        }
    });

    for (var keys in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(60 - keys)) {
            if (60 - keys == keys) {
                // take care of pairs
                // obj[keys] = x --> xC2
            } else {
                count += Math.min(obj[keys], obj[60 - keys]);
                delete obj[keys]
                delete obj[60 - keys];
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: A linear implementation of the combination function is okay because it’s linear with respect to the number of elements it represents. So the more work you have to do inside the combination function, the less it runs.

Comment: Your question title seems misleading. It says "find all the pairs that...", but then in your examples you seem to want to "find the count of pairs that...". Please clarify.

Comment: Remember, that "obj.hasOwnProperty" is not free call either. It would become more expensive as the number of properties is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no combination needed. It's simple math.

It's `n * (n-1) / 2`.

Let's say you have 4 items `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`.

Pairs would be:

- (a,b)
- (a,c)
- (a,d)
- (b,c)
- (b,d)
- (c,d)

For **4** items, we have **4 * 3 / 2 = 6**.

**#UPDATE:**

Change

```
count += Math.min(obj[keys], obj[60 - keys]);
```

to

```
count += obj[keys] * obj[60 - keys];
```

Consider 2 keys- `12` and `48`.

- Key `12` has elements - 12,72,132
- Key `48` has elements - 48,108

Technically, you are storing counts for them, which will be 3 and 2. 
If you observe, total no. of pairs we can make is **3 * 2 = 6** and not Math.min(3,2);

Answer (score 1):

You can compute *n*C2 in *O*(1) time, because *n*C2 = <sup>*n*!</sup>/<sub>(*n*−2)!·2!</sub> = <sup>*n*·(*n*−1)·(*n*−2)!</sup>/<sub>(*n*−2)!·2!</sub> = <sup>*n*·(*n*−1)</sup>/<sub>2!</sub> = <sup>*n*·(*n*−1)</sup>/<sub>2</sub>.

That said, you might want to consider a different approach: instead of having a separate loop to compute `count` based on `obj`, you can add to `count` as you are building `obj`. That might be more intuitive, since it eliminates the need for special cases. (Up to you.)

Incidentally, your `if (60 - keys == keys)` test is not correct; that will detect the case where `keys == 30`, but not the case where `keys == 0`. (There may also be some other bugs you'll need to sort through.)

Answer (score 0):

update: this solution is n^2, so this does not answer the original question.

```
let values = [60,10,20,50,40,30, 120, 60, 10];

let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for (let j = i+1; j < values.length; j++){
        let v = values[i] + values[j];
        if (v == 60 || !(v % 60)){
            count++;
        }
    }    
}
```

update 2:

To make it n + n*log(n), one could create a sorted tree with the mod values and then iterate through each of the mod value and look for 60-mod value values to find the number of pairs making up the difference. nodes can be optimised storing the number of repetitions as well. would that solve your problem?

Comment: This is still a quadratic time algorithm. It's O(n * (n-1)/2). If your array is `50` items long, the inner loop runs `1225` times. If it's `100` items long it runs `4950`.

Comment: Yep, but it's less than n^2 which as your original question.

Comment: Not really. It’s O(n^2). Here’s an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261895/big-oh-notation

Comment: Right, your are correct, let me see if I can propose a better option.

Comment: Added a n*log(n) solution idea, would that suit?

Answer (score 0):

If we count the pairs each element can make with the numbers seen so far, we can use simple addition rather than manage combinatorics or delicate edge cases.

```js
function f(A, m){
  const rs = new Array(m+1).fill(0);
  for (let x of A){
    if (rs[(m - x % m) % m])
      rs[m] += rs[(m - x % m) % m];
    rs[x % m]++;
  }
  return rs[m];
}

console.log(f([10, 50, 30, 30], 60));
console.log(f([30, 10, 50, 30, 30], 60));
console.log(f([1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 24], 6));
```

(By the way, I'm not sure why you are making a differentiation between two numbers that add up to 60 and pairs that sum to a value divisible by 60 since the former is contained in the latter.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int numPairsDivisibleBy60(vector<int>& time) {
    
    int n = (int)time.size(), ans = 0;
    
    int freq[61]{};

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        freq[time[i] % 60]++;
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= 30; ++i) {
        if(freq[i] >= 1) {
            if(i == 0 or i == 30) {
                ans += freq[i] * 1LL * (freq[i] - 1) / 2;
            } else {
                ans += freq[60 - i] * freq[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return ans;

}
```